# One to one annotation

Tags: hibernate

How can i use unique properties in one to one annotation?

Also I would like a list of properties available in one to one mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all available properties and how to use them, you only need to check docs for your correct version, go to the paragraph 'Optional Element Summary'

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html